# convert obj-c block to swift 2 closure

Tags: closures, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code -

```
[self.camera capture:^(LLSimpleCamera *camera, UIImage *image, NSDictionary *metadata, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {    
       }
}];
```

which, to me, should translate to

```
self.camera.capture({(camera: LLSimpleCamera, image: UIImage, metadata: [NSObject : AnyObject], error: NSError) -> Void in
    if !error {
    }
})
```

but it's throwing all the errors about 'cannot convert value of type etc, between the front and the return Void in section. Can someone tell me, is this a place when you have to use unSafeMutablePointers? If so, how would i know that.

Thanks!

Comment: can you expand on the compiler errors please, also is this objC code you wrote yourself?

Comment: Dude. Code completion just _hands_ you the right answer. Use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that these are nullables, so you need exclamation marks. So:

```
self.camera.capture { 
    (camera:LLSimpleCamera!, image:UIImage!, metadata:[NSObject : AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    // whatever
}
```

Or more compactly, just omit the types and let Swift infer them from the Objective-C declaration:

```
self.camera.capture { 
    camera, image, metadata, error in
    // whatever
}
```

Also, you can't say `!error` in Swift, but you can cross that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: aren't the parans around the curly brackets simply calling the camera method with the closure inside the arguments as opposed to passing it to the method as a trailing closure - which is only a matter of syntax and are really the same thing. eg. is `foo({...})` the same as `foo{...}`

Comment: @BlakeLockley Yep, fixed my answer. It was the nullable types.